# Multiple Ajax Webforms on One Page

Tags: ajax

I'm building a site with two webforms on one page, both with AJAX enabled. While the first form works perfectly fine, the second page refreshes after submission (it doesn't refresh if there's an error in the input). What should I do so that the two forms never refresh the page?